# How to write $P^{-1}$ in terms of $Q^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, block-matrices

I have the following $n \times n$ matrix

$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
 a & \begin{matrix} 0_{n-1}^{\top} \end{matrix} \\
 \begin{matrix} 0_{n-1} \end{matrix} & \text{ $Q$}
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $a \in \mathbb R$ and $Q$ is an $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix. Is it possible to find $P^{-1}$ in terms of $Q^{-1}$?

I am unable to come up with a technique to find $P^{-1}$ in terms of $Q^{-1}$. I will be grateful for some help.

Comment: You may find [this info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices) useful.

Comment: @A.Γ.; thank u so very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a block diagonal matrix. To invert it, simply invert each diagonal block, i.e. $$P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
 \tfrac{1}{a} & \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \end{matrix} \\
 \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\[1ex] 0 \end{matrix} & \text{ $Q^{-1}$}
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the help, so easy it was!!! how could i miss it

Answer (score 0):

How about:
$$
P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
 1/a & \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \end{matrix} \\
 \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\[1ex] 0 \end{matrix} & \text{ $Q^{-1}$}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This is what you get from Gaussian elimination $[P\mid I]\to\dots$